# My workspace cannot build because assimp library update

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody, i have a problem and I do not have any clue how to solve it.

Yesterday I updated my ubuntu 14.04 and with it, assimp was updated from 3.0 to 3.2.
Until then, when i try to build the project on which im working on, it gives me this error.

**/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libgeometric_shapes.so: undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::SetPropertyInteger(char const*, int, bool*)'**

I have been checking inside Importer file and the function SetPropertyInteger has the corresponding inputs.

i tried to downgrade from 3.2 to 3.0 but it makes me unistall all ros (i tried, and i does nto works, because when ros is installed again, the library is updated again also).

I searched info trough internet in several places and i didn't find any real clue of how to solve the error.

If anybdoy can help me, i would really feel very grateful.

PD: Yes, i think the problem is the version 3.2, not only because everything started to not work after the update, but also because my supervisor did not the upgrade and he can build correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269493/my-workspace-cannot-build-because-assimp-library-update/) by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2017-08-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-24**:
@Solrac3589: This would be better and more beneficial if the answer and question were separated.

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2017-08-25**:
Okey, i will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved myself the problem. I just let here how i did it just in case anybody needs it.

1-Install synaptic and do all the steps with it.

2-Force assimp3 to the 3.0 version (pyton-pyassimp ,assimp-dev and all ros was uninstalled).

3-Fix the broken package assimp3 (i do not know why, the package was marked as broken always).

4-bloc the version of assimp3.

5- install the two other assimp packages in version 3.0 also (fixing them to not be broken packages and blocking also the version). One by one.

6-install ros.

7-Profit

if anybody has the problem and need extra help, send me a message trough mail (i don't know if i will enter here frequently).

---

Originally posted by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) with karma: 187 on 2017-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31816/yashu/) on 2017-09-08**:
Hello I am facing similar problem.I have check the details and realized  ROS uses a library called assimp.
In my case it might gave me error because I installed cuda and Nvidia graphic card./opt/ros/indigo/lib/libgeometric_shapes.so: undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::SetPropertyInteger.

**Comment by [yashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31816/yashu/) on 2017-09-08**:
can you please explain me in details how you solve this problem. specifically I want to know how you bloc the version of assimp3. Thank you in advance.

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2017-09-08**:
in synaptic there is an option.

If you go to package menu at the top, you will see the option block version.

If you face more problems or you do not understand something, send me a mail and I will take time to solve the error with you this weekend (i am a little free).

**Comment by [yashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31816/yashu/) on 2017-09-08**:
Thank you very much for your reply. Now I will try above solution to solve my problem. I will contact you if I need any help. Thanks.

**Comment by [yashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31816/yashu/) on 2017-09-11**:
Thank you very much now its working fine.

**Comment by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) on 2017-09-29**:
Thanks for the help. I had the same issue and this solution solved it!!

**Comment by [ghanimmukhtar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19998/ghanimmukhtar/) on 2017-10-12**:
worked for me also, to fix the broken package status I needed to disable all PPA repositories in the software center

**Comment by [yashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31816/yashu/) on 2017-10-12**:
To fix broken assimp packages if you have Cuda and Nvidia graphic card (means if you are using GPU in your research) then carefully select modification method. Disable all PPA repositories in the software center might be responsible for Nvidia graphic card related error.

**Comment by [yashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31816/yashu/) on 2017-10-12**:
I am using GPU (Cuda and Nvidia graphic card) for my work. So to fix /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libgeometric_shapes.so: undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::SetPropertyInteger(char const, int, bool)' error I follow below method.
https://answers.ros.org/users/31816/yashu/#badges

**Comment by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on 2018-05-16**:
Hi, I'm facing the same issue but all of my assimp packages (assimp-utils, libassimp-dev/-doc/3, python-pyassimp) were at 3.2, but i reverted them to 3.0 and it still doesnt work. I'm not sure what's wrong... could u advise?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue on Indigo. I was able to resolve it without uninstalling ROS by using dpkg to remove the problem packages without removing their dependencies.

```
dpkg -r --force-depends package_name
```

So I ran the following:

```
dpkg -r --force-depends python-pyassimp assimp-*
```

This removed the problem packages, I then removed Cuda and ran `apt-get -f install` which reinstalled assimp with the correct version for indigo. I've been using it successfully since then without errors.

---

Originally posted by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) with karma: 147 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1